# Cannot mount USB pendrives in 13.10

Tags: usb, 13.10

I just upgrade to 13.10, and it doesn't mount any of my pendrives that was automatically mounted in 13.04. Did any one have this problem, or have any idea on how can I make 13.10 mount the pendrives?

Once I can't connect anything on the usb, and I'm also having [problems with the wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377282/13-10-doesnt-connect-wifi), I took pictures of some important outputs, requested by experienced users.

And, once I don't have enough reputation to post it here, they are in [this link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5p6LfVpTrxDUmtrbGVERHdNZlE&usp=sharing) to a folder in my drive:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this downgrading to 12.04 again. This solved my USB problem and a [wifi problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377282/13-10-doesnt-connect-wifi).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file system that your pendrive is formatted with. If you can see your pendrive listed with this command on Terminal (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) :

`$ fdisk -l`

if it is formatted with NTFS or FAT32 filesystem, Can you mount it with this command?

`$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

Also, paste the output here from Terminal for this command `lsusb`

You may also refer to help for [Mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount) in Ubuntu Documentation.

Comment: Thank you @ninad116. I put pictures of the outputs in the link on the questions, thank you for that. I couldn't mount even with `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`.