# 13.10 Doesn't Connect Wifi

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I know many people are having this problema, but any of the solutions seems to work. My wifi was working perfectly with 13.04, but when I updated to 13.10 it just seems that my laptop doesn't have a wifi.

As requested by experienced users in other posts, this is the output of `lspci`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 
14h Processor Root Complex 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, 
Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310] 00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, 
Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio 00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Port 00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
[AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] 00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, 
Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) 00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro 
Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) 00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced 
Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) 00:13.2 USB controller: 
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) 00:14.0 SMBus: 
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 14) 00:14.2 Audio device: 
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01) 00:14.3 ISA bridge: 
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11) 00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40) 00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) 00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced 
Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) 00:15.2 PCI bridge: 
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2) 00:18.0 Host 
bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43) 
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 
1 00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor 
Function 2 00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h 
Processor Function 3 00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 
12h/14h Processor Function 4 00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 
Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6 00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
[AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5 00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, 
Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek 
Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05) 
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe 07:00.1 
Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth 08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek 
Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01) 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: I've solved this downgrading to 12.04 again. This also solved my [USB problem][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377278/cannot-mount-usb-pendrives-in-13-10/379924#379924

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the RT3290 and upgraded the Ubuntu 13.10 kernel to 3.12 [as documented](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/linux-kernel-3-12-released-install-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/) and have not had a wireless problem since.

Comment: Thank you @Tim. I'll find a wired connection to try the upgrade or to try Mint as suggested by lonesword. Actually, 13.10 is also giving [another problem with USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377278/cannot-mount-usb-pendrives-in-13-10), so I can't even download the packages using Windows and take them to ubuntu. I'll let you know here as soon as I made it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend with the same problem. However, his problem was fixed when he upgraded to 13.10. He said under the 'drivers' section (search the dashboard) his adapter was listed among proprietary drivers.

Or else you can get cheap wifi adapters. Works like a charm in ubuntu. And better signal strength too.

Or try linux mint. Mint is basically ubuntu + proprietary drivers. So chances are that your wireless adapter will work in mint.

Comment: Thank you @lonesword. You made me really wanna try Mint. I'll let you know here if it worked.